# Which real applications use the Windows Workflow Foundation technology?

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation

I would like to investigate the Windows Workflow technology. In MSDN I have found a set of good samples. Could you write some examples of the real applications that use the Workflow technology?

Comment: Microsoft SharePoint server and many other commercial solutions use WF, but this question alone is against StackOverflow's FAQ.

Comment: Microsoft SharePoint it is a good example, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

My company uses it to visualize the business logic for several of our more complex systems including our order processing system. It makes it much easier to work with the business when we can visualize the work. We also have a couple of long running workflows for business process that can run for 3-6 months. I talk a little more about our uses cases for Workflow Foundation on .NETRocks 1236 http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?ShowNum=1236

Answer (score 0):

Windows Workflow foundation technology(WWF) is most commonly used in the following situations

Your process is a long running one.
You have a process that changes frequently.
You want a visual model of the process.

Read this post for more details
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pandrew/archive/2007/02/01/what-to-use-windows-workflow-foundation-for.aspx

WWF is most commonly used in WPF applications where the business logic is included in the sequence and it is executed. It's useful when the sequence is changed often and also supports re usability.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer in the "Introducing Windows Workflow Foundation" book, written by David Chappell.
There are four real business implementation: BizTalk Server; SharePoint Services; Microsoft Office System; Windows Communication Foundation.